# Plink in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, putty

How can I get [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to work in a PowerShell ISE window?

It seems to work just fine in a regular PowerShell command window, but it just hangs when I try to use it in ISE, and doesn't prompt for a user name or a password.

Anyone know what's going on here, or how to fix it?

Comment: Does it hang even if you run PowerShell ISE as admin?

Comment: Yeah, even then it still hangs.

Comment: I'm guessing it does something wonky when it tries to get input from the console that doesn't work in ISE. I'd recommend setting up a key pair and using Pageant to keep it around.